# Multiple cakephp projects with additional paths

Tags: php, cakephp, content-management-system

I'm creating a CMS in Cakephp. What I would like to do is to create 1 core project with al the basic controllers/models/views/...

Then I would like to create per website a projectfolder. That connects to the core project for its database/models/controllers and views. So that when I change something in the core project. It changed in all websites.

My folder structure is like this:
 - www
      - core (core project of the basic CMS)
         - Controller
         - Model
         - ...
      - lib (cakephp folder)
      - example.com (folder of the website project that uses the core CMS
         - Controller (extends controller from core project)
         - Model (same as controller)
         - ...

In the bootstrap of the example.com project I tried the following for my controllers:

```
App::build(array(
    'Controller' => array(
        ROOT.'core'.DS.'Controller'.DS,  
        APP.'Controller'.DS
    )
));
```

Then I called the pagescontroller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class AppPagesController extends PagesController {

    function index(){
        echo 'test';
        exit;
    }
}
```

But I get the following errors:
Fatal error: Class 'PagesController' not found in /www/liwebbe/Controller/PagesController.php on line 4

So he doesn't find the Pagescontroller from my core project.

Is there anyone who could help me. Google doens't find any related problems.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're importing `AppController`, not `PagesController`

Try changing:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

for:

```
App::uses('PagesController', 'Controller');
```